# hibernate paging with limiting OneToMany collecion's size?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

I am using spring 4.1.4.RELEASE + hibernate 4.3.6.Final, I have a question regarding the hibernate paging with limiting OneToMany collection's size, here is the code:

```
create table product (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(30)
);

create table picture (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    product_id varchar(30),
    url varchar(30)
);

@Entity(name = "product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Picture> pictures;

    public List<Picture> getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public void setPictures(List<Picture> pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }
}


@Entity(name = "picture")
public class Picture extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

The relationship between product and picture is OneToMany, now what I want is to get the list of products and to limit each product's picture size to 2, how could I achieve this?

I have tried the BatchSize, but it seems not working, even if this works, will I be able to get all results regardless that BatchSize if I want?

Someone said the only way is to find the list of product first, then find the 2 pictures for each product, is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally  Query.setMaxResults() should solve the problem but there are many approaches to it

1. You can use @Size

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
   @Size(min=1, max=2)
   private List pictures;
2. Also there is @BatchSize

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
   @BatchSize(size=2)
   private List pictures;
3. If still it doesn't work than we can go for native query with the help of group by query

Comment: in this case, how could I specify to get all pictures in the product?

Comment: You can set the size/ batch value dynamically

Comment: I added @BatchSize(size=2) above the class Picture and under OneToMany(I tried to put it above the getter as well), but it still doesn't work, did I miss something?

Comment: I opened another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818633/why-hibernate-onetomany-batchsize-is-not-working, there is log there.