# why hibernate OneToMany @BatchSize is not working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring 4.1.4.RELEASE + hibernate 4.3.6.Final, I am trying @BatchSize for OneToMany, but it seems not working, here is the code:

```
create table product (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(30)
);

create table picture (
    id int(6) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    product_id varchar(30),
    url varchar(30)
);

@Entity(name = "product")
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    @BatchSize(size=2)
    private List<Picture> pictures;

    public List<Picture> getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public void setPictures(List<Picture> pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }
}


@Entity(name = "picture")
@BatchSize(size=10)
public class Picture extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}


@Repository
public class ProductDao extends AbstractHibernateDao<Product> implements IProductDao {

    public ProductDao() {
        super();
        setClazz(Product.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Product find(final int id) {
        Product product = (Product) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
System.out.println("*--------------------find-------------------------");
System.out.println(product.getPictures());
System.out.println("*--------------------end-------------------------");

        return product;
    }
}
```

I tried to find Product by id, however the product doesn't contain any pictures inside, I tried to put the BatchSize above the getPictures as well, but it still doesn't work.

I am wondering if I missed some configuration or something, could anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the log:

```
[DEBUG] 2016-10-03 17:20:57.074 RequestMappingHandlerMapping:getHandlerInternal[302]: Returning handler method [public com.lehoolive.analyse.model.IResponse com.lehoolive.analyse.controller.ProductController.detail(int)]
[DEBUG] 2016-10-03 17:20:57.075 DispatcherServlet:doDispatch[931]: Last-Modified value for [/product/detail/1] is: -1
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id2_0_, product0_.name as name2_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.id=?
*--------------------find-------------------------
Hibernate: select pictures0_.product_id as product3_2_1_, pictures0_.id as id1_, pictures0_.id as id1_0_, pictures0_.product_id as product3_1_0_, pictures0_.url as url1_0_ from picture pictures0_ where pictures0_.product_id=?
[com.lehoolive.analyse.entity.Picture@29a0ce34, com.lehoolive.analyse.entity.Picture@5a7a10d8, com.lehoolive.analyse.entity.Picture@3e80350]
*--------------------end-------------------------
[DEBUG] 2016-10-03 17:20:57.333 ResponseBodyAdviceChain:invoke[61]: Invoking ResponseBodyAdvice chain for body=com.lehoolive.analyse.model.Response@59141f65
```

Comment: Batchsize has nothing to do with whether your pictures are there, just with how many statements Hibernate will use to get them.

Comment: What happens if you use `FetchType.EAGER` ?

Comment: @Asoub, FetchType.EAGER returns all pictures despite the batchsize=2

Comment: I guess it does work with FetchType.LAZY and no BatchSize annotation ? (ie: it also returns all the pictures)

Comment: @Asoub,yes, no matter what I tried, the BatchSize annotation seems not working, but LAZY works.

Comment: Wait, I think I miunderstood, when you put lazy and batchsize it does return all your pictures ? because, as Kirinya said, this is the normal behavior.

Comment: @Asoub, but how can I only return 2 pictures rather than all then?

Answer (score 0):

(From the comments)

There is no way to tell by default JPA that the getPictures() return a limited number of pictures (afaik). In general, I don't think you can limit the number of joined objects returned.

If you want to limit the number of pictures returned by the `find` method, you have to write your own method (`@BatchSize` only limits the number of `SELECTS` statements made, not the number of result).

You can do this with JPA: create a JPQL query on Pictures (not Product), then add `.setMaxResult(2)` before `.getResults()` (and you can get your product with `youPicturesList().get(0).getProduct();` )

Maybe you can do what you want with the `CriteriaBuilder` which may allow you to limit on joined entites, but I've never used it like this.